# SQL query to find id's and names of all good, that have all possible tags. Using SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, tags

I have tables:

**TAGS**

id: integer

name: text

**GOODS**

id: integer

name: text

**TAGS_GOODS**

tag_id: integer

goods_id: integer

*UNIQUE*(tag_id, goods_id)

So what I am asking for, is how can I found id's and names of goods that have all tags assigned. Sorry for beginner question. I will appreciate any help;)

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
SELECT g.id, g.name
FROM GOODS g
INNER JOIN TAGS_GOODS tg ON tg.goods_id = g.id
GROUP BY g.id, g.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TAGS);
```

The logic here is to aggregate by each good, and then assert that the number of records for that good matches the total number of available tags.  This answer assumes that each good and tag would be unique its own table, and that the junction table `TAGS_GOODS` also would not have repeated relationships.

Comment: Oh, yes seems I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use inner join

```
SELECT goods.id, goods.name FROM goods INNER JOIN tags_goods ON goods.id=tags_goods INNER JOIN tags ON tags_goods.id=tags_id;
```